# How to reach internet urls from inside containers

Tags: docker, rancher, k3s

Is there any way to get access to internet from inside a docker container?

My container have to reach some urls in order to work...

My containers are:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
457c79c831b6        rancher/k3s:v1.17.0-k3s.1   "/bin/k3s agent"         15 hours ago        Up 10 minutes                                k3d-k3s-default-worker-1
b9b39e82a6b2        rancher/k3s:v1.17.0-k3s.1   "/bin/k3s agent"         15 hours ago        Up 10 minutes                                k3d-k3s-default-worker-0
fb795905ec64        rancher/k3s:v1.17.0-k3s.1   "/bin/k3s server --h…"   15 hours ago        Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:6443->6443/tcp   k3d-k3s-default-server
```

As you can see, they are running `rancher/k3s:---` image.

I've took a look on logs:

> E0205 08:07:07.844781       6 kuberuntime_manager.go:729] createPodSandbox for pod "vault-helm-1580888075-agent-injector-b7647bf59-vght5_default(7210fa15-5ba4-4c61-9e2c-2bce05cd3bc0)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image "docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1": failed to pull image "docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1": failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/rancher/pause:3.1": failed to do request: Head https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/rancher/pause/manifests/3.1: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: Try again

It seems it's not able to reach `registry-1.docker.io` repository.

However, I'm able to pull images from my host:

```
$ docker pull busybox
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
bdbbaa22dec6: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:6915be4043561d64e0ab0f8f098dc2ac48e077fe23f488ac24b665166898115a
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
docker.io/library/busybox:latest
```

My host is working behind a coorporate proxy:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://10.49.0.1:8080/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.49.0.1:8080/"
Environment="NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,::1"
```

Also, I've tried to test if containers are able to reach proxy ip:

```
$ docker exec -it 457c79c831b6 sh
/ # ping 10.49.0.1
PING 10.49.0.1 (10.49.0.1): 56 data bytes
<no response>
```

**EDIT**

`/etc/resolv.conf` content:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

**EDIT 2**

Network related inspecttion of k3d master container node:

```
$ docker inspect k3d-k3s-default-server | grep -i networks -A10
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "57705be8c175394ac122b95f070321dbe48d4c7b7752482391fc243562babb75",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "6443/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "6443"
--
        "Networks": {
            "k3d-k3s-default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "k3d-k3s-default-server",
                    "fb795905ec64"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "337e73b268477428e97798665dd8013fd1e17d2003e33dcce694ab78f7f8b4bb",
                "EndpointID": "a35a783664dff4d68d199c6e23cd6d2c5a7cd0eac7a5f4b1691d524befe4ec01",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
```

**EDIT 3**

```
$ docker network inspect k3d-k3s-default
[
    {
        "Name": "k3d-k3s-default",
        "Id": "337e73b268477428e97798665dd8013fd1e17d2003e33dcce694ab78f7f8b4bb",
        "Created": "2020-02-04T17:40:01.13490488+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "457c79c831b6a76ae9b78cf360ae437eed04b18bd18429ac2e8436801ba0f4f7": {
                "Name": "k3d-k3s-default-worker-1",
                "EndpointID": "af38a2ecd618cf31df3dd4c88dea58ddc54de621e580934eb308105835f549d1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b9b39e82a6b2ef0863cbc8ed9f09cabbbcf8618fc14a2877feac9218b6803575": {
                "Name": "k3d-k3s-default-worker-0",
                "EndpointID": "87aacc1963289bca9097586cfc28fa17c7a98ee7716d5918a4c83143c35c8b00",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "fb795905ec64f99aac5ed1ad654d3e44a73e702327d15a91e4f60df4e5d03724": {
                "Name": "k3d-k3s-default-server",
                "EndpointID": "a35a783664dff4d68d199c6e23cd6d2c5a7cd0eac7a5f4b1691d524befe4ec01",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "app": "k3d",
            "cluster": "k3s-default"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Does it contain your corporate nameserver?

Comment: show also the result of `docker inspect k3d-k3s-default-server | grep -i networks -A10` to show its nework

Comment: now, `docker network inspect k3d-k3s-default`

Comment: I've added network inspection...

Comment: Check if your host does not have a firewall blocking connection to `docker0` via `tcpdump -i docker0`. Then go to a container and ping the docker0 address `172.17.0.1`. If nothing shows up on `tcpdump` may be a firewall issue